# Editable column's value not getting 'persisted' in AdvancedDataGrid

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I have an AdvancedDataGrid (whose dataProvider is a variable being bound from my main mxml file, not sure if this is relevant to my problem ). I'm setting one of the AdvancedDataGridColumn's editable property as true, and when I click on the cell in the UI, it is infact editable. But when I press enter/move to a different cell, the old value returns and the newly entered value is lost. Would anyone have any ideas why that's happening? Do I have to manually change the variable provided in the dataProvider?...I would think that would happen automatically right? I'd appreciate any help!

Thanks.

Comment: You should post some code or a simple example. In the most simplest case, the newly edited cell retains it's value after being edited.

Comment: Show some code for your AdvancedDataGrid along with the editable column, especially with your itemEditor.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It's flex 4. It's actually some proprietary code, and I'm not sure I understand it well enough to simplify and post an example here. Sorry for wasting ya'lls time.

Answer (score 0):

This traces out correct when I edit a field and press enter then click on the button to see trace output:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" applicationComplete="init()">
        <fx:Declarations>
          <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
        </fx:Declarations>
        <fx:Script>
          <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.HierarchicalData;
            [Bindable]
            private var companyHierarchy:HierarchicalData;

            private var companyData:XML = <data>
                        <company name="Employees">
                          <department name="Unit 1">
                            <employee name="Dave" func="C# Developer"/>
                            <employee name="Bob" func="AS3 Developer"/>
                            <employee name="Clair" func="AS3 Architect"/>
                          </department>
                          <department name="Unit 2">
                            <employee name="John" func="ORACLE Developer"/>
                            <employee name="Sandra" func="HTML Developer"/>
                          </department>
                        </company>
                      </data>;


            private function init():void
            {
              companyHierarchy = new HierarchicalData(companyData.company);
            }

            private function checkSetData():void
            {
              trace(companyData);
            }
          ]]>
        </fx:Script>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="test" width="500" height="500" dataProvider="{companyHierarchy}"
                   displayItemsExpanded="true" editable="true" enabled="true">
          <mx:columns>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="@name"
                           headerText="Companies"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="@func"
                           headerText="Function"/>
          </mx:columns>
        </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
        <s:Button x="205" y="508" label="Button" click="checkSetData()"/>
      </s:Application>
```